# Variable of type Date becomes undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, datepicker, undefined

I have the following code:

```
Some.SomeControl = {
    model: {
        // ...
        currentDateOnDayTab: new Date(),
        // ...             
    },

    hookUpEvents: function hookUpEvents() {
        var self = this;
        $('.datepicker-input').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
            onClose: function () {
                var a = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                self.model.currentDateOnDayTab = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the `onClose` function when I set the value for the `a` variable, it will have the value of the selected date of the datepicker and the `self.model.currentDateOnDayTab` has the value of the current date, but after I set the value for `currentDateOnDayTab` in the next line, the `currentDateOnDayTab` becomes `undefined`.

Can someone explain me why is this happening, and how can I handle this problem?

Comment: Does `this` refer to the actual `datepicker` you think it does?

Comment: I can set the value of the `a` variable using `$(this).datepicker('getDate')`, so the code in the right side of the '=' it's ok.